# How to create a label that show continuous coordinates of mouse C#

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling

How to create a label that show continuous coordinates of mouse C#

I tested a few different options, and I feel like a timer tick event would be the best to update the label consistantly. But I am doing something wrong and I can't seem to get it working.

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point position = Cursor.Position;
            position = Cursor.Position;
            int x = position.X;
            int y = position.Y;
            string str = x.ToString() + ":" + y.ToString();
            coords.Text = str;

        }
```

Comment: What is not working correctly, please specifiy. Is the label not showing any content? Is it not updating? Are the coordinates incorrect?

Comment: The label didnt update at all. -- the timer wasn't enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple MouseMove event?!
Assuming you are using WinForms this very simple code shows the mouse location on a Form:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = $"{e.X:0},{e.Y:0}";
}
```

And for the less efficient Timer approach:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = $"{Cursor.Position.X:0},{Cursor.Position.Y:0}";
}
```

Just make sure to set the `Timer.Enabled` to `True` for it to work.

Comment: The coordinates should be visible on the whole screen, not only the Form. That's why I couldn't use MouseMove event. 

The Timer wasn't enabled (so dumb) hahahaha 
Thanks so much